# Typescript - Simplifying this statement this.active = data.active !== undefined ? data.active : true;

Tags: javascript, typescript

As per the title I want to know if there is a more effective way to write the above statement?

`Perhaps this.active = data.active || true?`

Comment: It really depends on the possible values of `data.active`, and for that we'd need a [mcve].

Comment: sorry data.active can be either true/false. Also this shouldn't need full code its more of a thought experiment if someone has had a similar situation.

Comment: sorry true/false or undefined...

Comment: If data.active only be true or false, why you checking then if data.active !== undefined?! .... and no ```this.active = data.active || true``` is not the same as ```this.active = data.active !== undefined ? data.active : true;``` for data.acive = false

Comment: A minimum reproducible example doesn't mean "full code", it's "enough code to reproduce".  Since you're treating `false` and `undefined` as separate cases, you can't use truthiness/falsiness checks... try `this.active = data.active !== false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.active = data.active || true` would work if `data.active` is always either [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or `undefined`. If not, the ternary is the only (good) way.

Comment: "the ternary is the only (good) way"...  given that (according to the comments) `data.active` is always either `true`, `false`, or `undefined`... is something not "good" about `data.active !== false`?

Comment: @jcalz ah, right, that'll work too .. .but I'm not sure about readability, I'd still prefer the ternary